# Toggle between high and low res image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an div on my page that has an image inside of it, on click the div expands and i swap the image for the corresponding hi resolution version.

I'm doing this with the following...

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
        var img = $(this).find('ul li img');
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return '_includes/images/work/hires/' + value;
        });
    } else { 
        var img = $(this).find('ul li img');
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return '' + value;
        });

    };
});
```

My problem is the last part however I need to remove ''_includes/images/work/hires/''

Can anybody recommend a solution?

Comment: Solution to what exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the appended path to restore previous url, you can use [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to remove the prepended path.

Change

```
 return '' + value;
```

To

```
 return  value.replace('_includes/images/work/hires/', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var path = '_includes/images/work/hires/';
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
        var img = $(this).find('ul li img');
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return path + value;
        });
    } else { 
        var img = $(this).find('ul li img');
        img.attr('src', function(i, value) {
            return value.substring(path.length);
        });

    };
});
```

Here is the document about substring() http://www.w3school.com.cn/js/jsref_substring.asp.

Comment: I suggest avoiding magic numbers (`28`), so a solution like Adil's one or something like `var path = '_includes/images/work/hires/';` and in the first case : `return path + value;` and in the second one : `return value.substring(path.length);`.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie All right I can change the 28 to `path.length`. And I will update the code soon.